# numpy "extend/append" ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

**The problem:**

I have a numpy array

```
tf = numpy.full((500, 4, 1, 2), [500, 1])

tf : 
array([[[[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]]],

   ..., 
   [[[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]]]])


tf.shape :
(500, 4, 1, 2)
```

Consider the first group:
`tf[0][0]` this is : `array([[ 500.,    1.]])`

I need to be able to append (in place) additional values say `[[100, 0.33], [1, 0.34], [15, 0.33]]` so that the end result looks like (this operation is carried out for each of the elements):

```
tf : 
array([[[[ 500.,  1.], [100.,  0.33], [1.,  0.34], [15.,   0.33]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]]],

   ..., 
   [[[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]],

    [[ 500.,    1.]]]])
```

I tried `numpy.concatenate((tf[0][0], [[100, 0.33]]), axis = 0)` this returns a new appended ndarray, but I cannot assign it back to `tf[0][0]` as it fails with the following error. 
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (1,2)`

Is there any other way to achieve what I want using numpy?

==========================================================

**Inefficient `list` way of doing it:**

```
# initialization
tf = [[[]] for i in xrange(500)]
for i in xrange(500):
    tf[i] = [[] for a in xrange(4)]
    for j in xrange(4):
        tf[i][j].append([500, 1.0])

# usage: (for any 0 < i < 500; 0 < j < 4 )

tf[i][j].append([100, 0.33])
```

but this is inefficient (considering I need to do this over a million times)

Comment: You cannot do this using `numpy.ndarrays` which are true, fixed-size multidimensional arrays. The efficient way to do this is with a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `this operation is carried out for each of the elements` - So it seems it won't be a ragged array, but a regular one.

Comment: A follow up question, then would be, how can I convert this nested list effectively into ndarray for further processing?

Comment: @Divakar perhaps, OP can elaborate.

Comment: @Divakar juanpa.arrivillaga it is a ragged.

Comment: err.. just to be clear, the number of items to be appended is not fixed to 4. it can be more or less (or none!)

Comment: @okkhoy to convert to an `ndarray` your only option is to use some sort of `dtype=object` array, which will essentially be a bad list. In what sense of "inefficient" do you mean "inefficient list way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your approach is  that the shape of each element varies and hence you cannot have a fixed shape. However you can define each element as type `object` and achieve what you are trying to do.

```
import numpy as np

tf = np.empty((500, 4, 1), dtype= object)
```

will produce

```
array([[[None],
        [None],
        [None],
        [None]],

       [[None],
        [None],
        [None],
        [None]],

       [[None],
        [None],
        [None],
        [None]],

       ...,
       [[None],
        [None],
        [None],
        [None]],

       [[None],
        [None],
        [None],
        [None]],

       [[None],
        [None],
        [None],
        [None]]], dtype=object)
```

Now add your constant initial element as a list to each of these array elements.  You might be tempted to use `fill()` here, but that assigns a single object to each array element and modifying individual array elements will change the entire array. To initialize, you cannot avoid iterating through the entire array.

```
for i,v in enumerate(tf):
    for j,w in enumerate(v):
        tf[i][j][0] = [[500.0,1.0]]
```

will produce

```
array([[[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       ...,
       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]]], dtype=object)
```

Now you can access each element separately. Use append or extend as you prefer.

```
 tf[0][0][0].append([100,0.33])
```

will give

```
array([[[list([[500.0, 1.0], [100, 0.33]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       ...,
       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]],

       [[list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])],
        [list([[500.0, 1.0]])]]], dtype=object)
```

Only the initialization requires iterating through the array.

Comment: I have a follow up question, can I use this as a normal numpy array later; e.g., to do array multiplication, dot product etc?

Comment: I didn't get that. Can you explain?

Comment: sorry! what I meant was: The deepest data type is a `list` , so was wondering if I can use numpy operations like dot, ndarray multiplication etc.,

Comment: It depends on the operation. I suggest that after appending all required elements, you can iterate over the array and convert each individual list to a numpy array. This way scalar operations and  few other array-wide operations should work.

Comment: @okkhoy, math operations with an object dtype array are hit and miss.  Some propagate to the objects, some don't.  All will slower than with regular arrays.  Indexing may be slower than with a list.  Test small cases first.